# Could not parse the remainder: '/{{menu.Info.page}}' from ''item'/{{menu.Info.Page}}'

Tags: django, django-templates

```
 <a href="{% url 'page' %}"><img id="page" class="abc" src="{{STATIC_URL}}page/code_251.png" style=""/></a>
```

Hitting this url like localhost:8000/app/page works fine.

If I want something from views and append that pageid with url then showing error as Couldn't parse.
 From views:`{{page.pageid}}`

output url should be :`localhost:8000/app/?pageid=xx`

for this i tried with below syntax:

```
<a href="{% url 'page'/?pageid={{page.pageid}} %}"><img id="page" class="abc" src="{{STATIC_URL}}page/code_251.png" style=""/></a>
```

But above syntax did't worked for me.
**urls.py**

```
url(r'^(page)(?:/(?P<page_id>[0-9]+))?/$',page_ViewDetails_TemplateView.as_view(),name="page"),
```

May be some changes need to be done on urls.py as well.
Can someone share some idea!!

Comment: Your syntax makes no sense. But please post the relevant part of your urls.py.

Comment: I have updated the Q.Please see!!!

Answer (score 0):

You're confused about at least two things here.

Firstly, you would never use `{{ }}` *inside* a tag. You're already in the template language context there: you have access to variables directly.

Secondly, the `{% url %}` tag works on urlpattern names and parameters, not literal URLs. And your `page` URL does not expect a querystring value for `page_id`: it expects it *as part of the path*. Your generated URL needs to be "/page/3", not "/page?page_id=3".

So your URL tag is just:

```
<a href="{% url 'page' page_id=page.pageid %}">
```

Comment: :Again I have updated urls.py for adding optional parameter.Will the answer given above will work?